Excel - Formula help - If A2 = !A2:A4, highlight !B2:B4 IFNOT = B2
I have 2 large workbooks of employee data and need to express the following in a formula.
Workbook 1:



Employee ID
First Name




00000001
Sam


00000002
Fred


00000003
Bob



Workbook 2:



Employee ID
First Name




00000003
Bobb


00000002
Fred


00000001
Sammy



If A2 in workbook 1, is an exact match with any cell in column A of workbook 2, then highlight B of the same row of the returned cell from workbook 2 if it is NOT an exact match with B2 in workbook 1.
I hope that makes sense! The client uses Office 2016 and xlookup is not an option.
Many thanks

If XLOOKUP is not an option, VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH should do the job

It looks like you're trying to do conditional formatting with data spread over two different workbooks. This isn't possible (through direct conditional formatting, could be done through VBA I think). Or did you mess up workbook (different files) and worksheet (different sheet within the same file)?

@Excellor thank you I appreciate it. No they are in different workbooks unfortunately, but could be moved to the same offline workbook for the sake of making calculations as long as I can track that but thanks for the insight

@cybernetic.nomad Thanks a lot

@AlexSpink you could use helper columns where it refers to the other file. Not sure if that's an option.
